# How to get the DIC from within a data fixture (or anywhere else)?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-2.1

I want to use a [data fixture](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) to create users for testing purposes.

The problem is I need the FOS' user manager:

```
$userManager = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
```

And for that I need the container. So how do I get it? It's not like when inside a controller, I can't do `$this->get('fos_user.user_manager')`.

Comment: You haven't read the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#using-the-container-in-the-fixtures) till end :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest [solution](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#using-the-container-in-the-fixtures) is to extend Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware.

```
<?php

namespace SomeCompany\SomeBundle\DataFixtures\MongoDB;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

use SomeCompany\SomeBundle\Document\User;

class LoadUsers extends ContainerAware implements FixtureInterface
{   
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user = $userManager->createUser();

        $user->setUsername('myuser');
        $user->setEmail('a@a.com');

        $user->setPlainPassword('mypass');
        $user->addRole('ROLE_USER');
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
    }
}
```

If you are already extending another class, then you have to implement the ContainerAwareInterface, which takes just a few extra lines of code.

Comment: Please, add link to documentation in your answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this only works of you use the console. Loading fixtures via the API does not work well with container awareness and leads to errors, freezes and other issues.

Comment: What are you talking about? Show some code. As far as I know fixtures are for creating fake data to work with, or initial data like basic roles. Why do you need an API? Just run the command.

Comment: If you want to include it in your unit testing, then you want to call it via the API in your setUp() method. At least that's the theory.

I would show could, but I've reversed it all out. If you doubt me, write a simple unit test that uses both fixtures and container awareness. I tried for half a day and none of the 20 approaches listed online works and some result in phpunit freezing or entering an infinite loop.